# graph is not saved

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

First, I follow these steps to create a graph in JanusGraph.

- add the following to `conf/janusgraph-cassandra-configurationgraph.properties`

```
index.search.backend = elasticsearch
index.search.hostname = 127.0.0.1
index.search.elasticsearch.transport-scheme = http
```

- change "ConfigurationManagementGraph: conf/janusgraph-cql-configurationgraph.properties" in gremlin-server-configuration.yaml to "ConfigurationManagementGraph: conf/janusgraph-cassandra-configurationgraph.properties"
- change conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml to conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml.orig
- change conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-configuration.yaml to conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
- run bin/janusgraph.sh start
- run bin/gremlin.sh
- run

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
:remote console

map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("storage.backend", "cassandrathrift");
map.put("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1");
map.put("graph.graphname", "KG");
map.put("index.search.backend", "elasticsearch");
map.put("index.search.hostname", "127.0.0.1");
map.put("index.search.elasticsearch.transport-scheme", "http");

ConfiguredGraphFactory.createConfiguration(new MapConfiguration(map));
graph=ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("KG");

g=graph.traversal();


ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames()
```

- turn off janusgraph, run bin/janusgraph.sh stop
- make a copy of conf/janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties to conf/KG.properties
- add the following two lines to the top of conf/KG.properties

```
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.ConfiguredGraphFactory
graph.graphname=KG
```

- open conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml, and add the following line to graphs:

```
KG: conf/KG.properties
```

- add "scripts/empty-sample.groovy" to "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin:"
- open script/empty-sample.groovy, change the last line to the following:

```
globals << [g : KG.traversal()]
```

- start janusgraph again by running bin/janusgraph.sh start

Second, I run bin/gremlin.sh

- run

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
:remote console
graph=ConfiguredGraphFactory.open("KG");
g=graph.traversal();
g.addV('user').property('name', 'Robert')
g.V()
```

- I can see it returns a vertex `==>v[4120]`

Third, however, when I exit from gremlin console, and get into the gremlin console again like above, when I try to query g.V(), I see nothing returned.

Any idea why this is happening? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because you failed to close the transaction with `g.tx().commit()` after you add your vertex.

Note that Gremlin Server does manage sessions and calls `commit()` for you, but by doing:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
```

you've explicitly opened a connection that does not manage sessions. If you want a session that is managed and auto-commits on every request then you need to do:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session-managed
```

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#console-sessions

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what my problem is.